# unable to pass float value as sqlparameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My query is like this

```
    DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(GlobalSettings.DbDSN, CommandType.Text, 

 "SELECT TOP 1000 [ID],[Project]," +
         "[Owner], " +
         "[Consultant], " +
         "[Contractor], " +
         "[Value], " +
         "[Level1], " +
         "[Level2], " + 
         "[Status], " +
         "[Category], " +
         "[Country], " + 
         "[CreatedDate], " + 
         "[CreatedByID], " +
         "[CreatedByName] " +
   "FROM [Kontorting_Umbraco_DB].[dbo].[tbl_Projects] " +
  " where [Category] like '%' + @Category + '%' " + 
  "   and Country like'%'+ @country+'%' " + 
  "   and value like '%'+@Value+'%' " + 
  "        order by CreatedDate asc",

              new SqlParameter("@Category","water") ,
              new SqlParameter("@Country", "Bahrain"),
              new SqlParameter("@Value", 1000));
```

In this code "Value" field is float in the DB..And when I executes this I am getting an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.

can any one tell me how to use like query with float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing

```
value like '%'+@Value+'%'
```

, where `value` is `int`.

[`LIKE` only works with expressions of character data type.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

You could do

```
convert(nvarchar(100), value) like '%' + convert(nvarchar(100), @Value) + '%'
```

instead.

Note that you may have to adjust the length of the data (currently 100).